# Why complexity of first code is more than that of second one?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Append has constant time complexity O(1). Extend has O(n) complexity as in my case k(the number of elements to be added)=n-1. Insert and del both have O(n) time complexity. Then why first code is taking longer time than second one?
1. First piece of code

```
def circularArrayRotation(a,n, queries):      
  for _ in range(n):
      arr=[]
      arr.append(a[-1])
      arr.extend(a[0:-1])
      a=arr          
  for j in queries:
      yield a[j]
```

2. Second piece of code

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, n, queries):
    for _ in range(n):
        a.insert(0, a[-1])
        del a[-1]
    for j in queries:
        yield a[j]
```

Comment: in real life some commands need more time to run (and you run more commands inside loop) but it is still the same complexity `O(n)`. `O(n)` doesn't meen it will run exactly the same time.

Comment: The second modifies the array in-place, so is a much more efficient implementation of doing the circular rotation this way. Note that significantly more efficient solutions are possible, especially as it seems you don't even need the array to be rotated -- only the queries answered.

Comment: @furas, I do agree with you. But could you please tell the actual complexity of these both codes

Comment: @Paul, Could you suggest the way to solve this problem without rotation.

Comment: if `del` and `insert` have `O(n)` so together have `n+n`. Because they are in `for`-loop which is executed n-times then it gives `n * (n+ n)` which means `2*n*n` or using `**` as `power` - `2*n**2` or using `^` as `power` - `2*n^2` - so you have `O(2*n^2)` which is treated as `O(n^2)`. In first code `append` has `O(1)` and `extend` has `0(n)` so together they have `n+1`. Because they are in loop which is execute n-times so you have `n*(n+1)` which give `O(n^2 + n)` but it is treated as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: In both you have second loop `for j in queries:` but probably it can be treated as `O(n)` so together with first loop (in both versions) you would have `O(n^2 + n)` but it is treated as `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure. But My assumption is because in first code you call `arr.extend(a[0:-1])` which has to make a temporary sub-list. The creation of sub-list will take extra time. I would assume the creation of sub-list would be something like `O(M)` where `M` is size of sublist.

**Edit**:
Plus in Big O, you have `O(2N) = O(N)`. But in practice that still affects performance, just not as significant as anything else.